# How to duplicate all the frames in the same .tif file

Tags: python, imaging

I have a tif file that has 203 frames. I want to duplicate the frames to 406 in the original file. What should I do in Python?

I also tried to combine the same .tif and create a new file, but it says the second file is unused.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question, and add the code that is not working. Please explain what you mean by "duplicate the frames". For example, duplicating ABC to AABBCC or to ABCABC. Try to share the input Tiff file or some other sample multiframe Tiff file, or at least describe the content of a frame (e.g are all the frames with the same resolution? grayscale or colored?).